# Sequence of positive numbers

Tags: number-theory

$(1)$ Suppose $\{\alpha_n\}$ and $\{\beta_n\}$ are sequence of real numbers where $\alpha_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\alpha_n\sim\beta_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. 
Prove that $\alpha_n \log \alpha_n \sim\beta_n \log\beta_n $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  
 My proof : Since $\alpha_n\sim\beta_n$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}=1$. Now observe that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha_n \log \alpha_n}{\beta_n \log\beta_n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log \alpha_n}{\log \beta_n}.$$ So $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log \alpha_n}{\log \beta_n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\alpha_n}/\frac{1}{\beta_n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\beta_n}{\alpha_n}=1 \;\;\;(\text{as} \; n \rightarrow \infty).$$ Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: What is $p_n$? in part 2?

Comment: The nth Prime. Sorry

Comment: You may wish to add that to your question for clarity.

Comment: It'd be great too to define ~.

Comment: I deleted the other questions i think i know how to proceed thank you very much!!